# System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate not working for Chrome?

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight provides Navigate to open new browser window from code. it's working fine with IE. but same code not working with Chrome.

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("file://Mysite/Mydrive/Myfolder", "_blank");
```

Run with IE, it will open new  Windows Explore point to the network drive
Run with Chrome, will open new blank Chrome windows with url about:blank.

If put "file://Mysite/Mydrive/Myfolder" in url line in Chrome directly, it will list the folder, files in this folder in Chrome windows like:

```
Index of //Mysite/Mydrive/Myfolder
Name    Size    Date Modified
[parent directory]      
Folder1/        8/1/12 11:17:16 AM
Folder2/        8/1/12 11:17:24 AM
File1.txt   8.5 kB  8/9/12 2:14:47 PM
File2.docx  12.4 kB 8/9/12 2:18:13 PM
```

how to make it working fine for Chrome?